# Vaadin Spring integration add-on doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I'm developing an application using Spring and Vaadin across SpringVaadinIntegration add-on, now when i inject the service in my main Vaadin UI class everythings work well, the problem is then i use this annotation in others class

This is MyService

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class MyService {

public MyService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public String getLabel(){
    return "this is my label";
}

public void saveUser(Utente utente){
    System.out.println("save user");
}

}
```

This is my main Vaadin UI class

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyUI extends UI
{

@Autowired
private transient ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired
private MyService myService;

private MainPanel mainPanel;

private VerticalLayout verticalLayout; 




@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();

    mainPanel = new MainPanel();
    verticalLayout.addComponent(mainPanel);
    setContent(verticalLayout);


}
  }
```

in MyUI the @autowired work in fact myservice is not null while in Main panel doesn't work

```
@Component
public class MainPanel extends CustomComponent implements View {

private VerticalLayout mainLayout;

private Button button;

@Autowired
MyService  secondService;

public MainPanel() {
    buildMainLayout();
    setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);

    // TODO add user code here
}

@AutoGenerated
private VerticalLayout buildMainLayout() {
    // common part: create layout
    button = new Button();
    mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    mainLayout.addComponent(button);

    button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            secondService.saveUser(new Utente());

        }
    }); 


    return mainLayout;
}
 }
```

Here where I try to save the user, the service is null.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi. I am having the same problem. did you figure out what the problem was?

Comment: I have solved in a different way, if you want some suggestion tell me how I can contact you

Comment: thanks, but i just figured out how to deal with it. https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/1811101

Answer (score 0):

You have created MainPanel as "new MainPanel();" so the main panel is not a Spring Bean so any injection won't take place.

Replace this MainPanel with Spring injection with maybe ptototype scope and any injection within MainPanel will be ok.